# How to write find clause using where user_id =current_user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a one to many relationship between 1 user and many challenges. I am using rails 4 with Devise

I would like to list the challenges for the current user.

So far I have

```
@challenge = User.find(current_user.id).challenges
```

and I've also tried

```
@challenge = User.find(current_user).challenges
```

and I also tried `@challenge = current_user.challenges`

but it doesn't work. I get the error `"undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass"`  which usually means @challenge isn't being passed over to the view Have I made some kind of syntax error?

if I do `User.find(1).challenges` in the rails console it works fine so presumably I'm not using current_user.id correctly

Comment: Are you sure `current_user` is set (that user is authorised)?Do you have any  `before` filters to acknowledge that?

Comment: Your query is correct. The problem could `current_user` is not set.

Comment: Can you post the part of the view in which you access the `@challenge` and the part of the model in which you define the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you are trying to access the page user is not logged in and hence `current_user` is set to `nil`.

`current_user.challenges` will do the job of fetching all `challenges` associated to this user. You can use `user_signed_in?` method from `devise` before calling this code to ensure `current_user` is always available.